# Hadamard/Phase/Hadamard and Inversion about the Mean

Tags: grovers-algorithm, hadamard

I understand the matrix multiplication behind Grover's algorithm, but I'd like to get an intuitive grasp on why sequence of gates *Hadamard-Phase-Hadamard* does inversion about the mean. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether it's completely intuitive if it still has some formulas in it, but here's a try. (I prefer term "reflection", since it makes the geometrical interpretation a bit simpler, but I think they are used interchangeably.)

1. First, let's convince ourselves that Controlled Z does inversion about the $|1...1\rangle$ state.
   Controlled Z flips the phase of $|1...1\rangle$ basis state and keeps the phases of other states unchanged, so it can be written as $\mathcal{I} - 2|1...1\rangle \langle 1...1|$, which is the reflection about the $|1...1\rangle$ (with an extra global phase of -1, which can be ignored).
2. Second, let's see how to represent reflection about any state $|\psi\rangle$ in terms of reflection about the $|1...1\rangle$ state, given that we know a unitary $U$ that prepares state $|\psi\rangle$ from the $|1...1\rangle$, i.e., $|\psi\rangle = U|1...1\rangle$.
   Reflection about $|\psi\rangle$ is

   $$2|\psi\rangle \langle \psi| - \mathcal{I} = 2 U|1...1\rangle \langle 1...1|U^\dagger - \mathcal{I} = U(2|1...1\rangle \langle 1...1| - \mathcal{I})U^\dagger$$

   So you can represent that reflection by applying the following sequence of steps:

   - $U^\dagger$
   - reflection about the $|1...1\rangle$
   - $U$
3. Finally, let's see how to prepare the mean state $\sum_j |j\rangle$, starting with the $|1...1\rangle$ state.
   The easiest way is to apply X gate to each qubit to get $|0...0\rangle$, and then to apply H gate to each qubit to get an equal superposition of all basis states.

Putting this all together, we get the following procedure:

- apply H to each qubit
- apply X to each qubit
- apply Controlled Z with most qubits as control and last qubit as target
- apply X to each qubit
- apply H to each qubit